# Add to SortedSet<T> and its complexity

Tags: c#, time-complexity, sortedset

MSDN states the following [SortedSet(T).Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411709%28VS.100%29.aspx) :

> If Count  is less than the capacity of the internal array, this method is an O(1) operation.

Could someone please explain "how so"? I mean when adding new value we need to find a correct place to add a value (comparing it with another values) and internal implementation looks like a "Red-Black tree" with O (log N) insertion complexity.

Comment: They have changed it since then

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The comment is simply wrong.  Yes, it is a red-black tree, O(log(n)) for inserts.  Taking a look with Reflector bears this out, the private [AddIfNotPresent()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedset.cs,357) method contains a while() loop to find the insertion point, using normal red-black node traversal.

Comment: fyi, link is now bad

Comment: This is confirmed by the `SortedSet<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` documentation which states that its complexity is O(n log(n)).